# Android Jetpack compose material 3 why Card need this annotation @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-ui, android-compose-card

I am new in Jetpack Compose(JC).
I started JC and used card but it shows me an error and recommend me to add this annotation `@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)`.

Also showing this message ***This material API is experimental and is likely to change or to be removed in the future.***
My Question that if this is experimental and might have changes in future what is the normal and **stable way to use card** in jetpack compose Material3?

What does this annotation actually means and what if I don't want to use experimental or thing which is not stable.

As I also find that Material3 is stable.

> https://material.io/blog/material-3-compose-stable

Clarify me if you think that I don't understand this correctly or provide the appropriate fix.

Thx!

Comment: There are two Card composables in Material3, one has `onClick` argument and is experimental - that's the one you are talking about, the other doesn't have onClick argument and is not experimental. The annotation means pretty much what it says, the api may change in the future. If you don't want to use experimental stuff, you can find stable alternative or implement it yourself.

Comment: https://www.linkpicture.com/q/Untitled_508.png. 
I used a card with no onClick arguments still it's tell me to add that annotation.

Comment: Which version are you using? It shouldn't be experimental since 1.0.0-alpha15. https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/2138161

Comment: I am using alpha11.
'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.0-alpha11'

Comment: Yeah then you should probably upgrade. Either to latest stable version `1.0.1`, or latest alpha `1.1.0-alpha08`

Comment: Yes it worked for Card without onClick.
But do you know what is the alternative for the Card with onclick in Compose bcz Material 3 is stable now and the Card is in experiment state that's strange!

Comment: I'd just use it. If you look it the implementation, Card is just Surface with customized color, shape and elevation. And card with onClick only passes the onClick to that Surface (which is not experimental!). I don't know why the card itself is experimental tbh.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252709/discussion-between-mohammad-taqi-and-jan-bina).

Answer (score 0):

Same here! i didn't understand it too so what i do is i check if my android studio is updated and it seems like it is not, so i update it and then create a new project. it works in me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The OptIn annotation in Jetpack Compose indicates that a class or function is experimental and should only be used with caution. It allows developers to use features still in development that may change or be removed in future releases.

When using an OptIn-annotated class or function, you must explicitly opt into using it by adding the @OptIn annotation to the class or function that calls it. This helps to ensure that you are aware of the potential risks of using experimental features and taking appropriate precautions.

Comment: My Question that if this is experimental and might have changes in future what is the normal and stable way to use card in jetpack compose Material3?

Answer (score -3):

```
buildFeatures {
    compose true
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs += [
                "-opt-in=kotlin.ExperimentalUnsignedTypes",
                "-opt-in=kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi",
                "-opt-in=kotlinx.coroutines.InternalCoroutinesApi",
                "-opt-in=androidx.compose.animation.ExperimentalAnimationApi",
                "-opt-in=androidx.compose.ExperimentalComposeApi",
                "-opt-in=androidx.compose.material.ExperimentalMaterialApi",
                "-opt-in=androidx.compose.runtime.ExperimentalComposeApi",
                "-opt-in=androidx.compose.ui.ExperimentalComposeUiApi",
                "-opt-in=androidx.compose.material3.ExperimentalMaterial3Api",
                "-opt-in=coil.annotation.ExperimentalCoilApi",
                "-opt-in=kotlinx.serialization.ExperimentalSerializationApi",
                "-opt-in=com.google.accompanist.pager.ExperimentalPagerApi",
                "-opt-in=com.google.accompanist.navigation.material.ExperimentalMaterialNavigationApi"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Nowhere in this chunk of text is explained the reason of *why* the annotation is needed, what it does, and what consequences or side effects is produces. You're merely choosing to include them all with no knowledge of what they do. Please don't do this unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That just hides the fact you are using experimental.  Why do we need any experimental widgets when M3 is now stable?